# AWS Lambda function for oracle password rotation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

Hi I am using lambda function for oracle password rotation and am getting the below error once every grants provided:

```
START RequestId: f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2 Version: $LATEST
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:14.9Z  f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    {'RequestType': 'Create', 'ServiceToken': 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:661211433270:function:oracle-rds-dbsetup-lambda', 'ResponseURL': 'https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-euwest1.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-west-1%3A661211433270%3Astack/oracle/24520dd0-95e8-11ea-b1d1-0609694b6370%7CRDSDBSetup%7Cff43fa14-be13-4a66-95e5-ee0b82a44993?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200514T135412Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7MCS7PVEUOADEEA%2F20200514%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=20bb8ba39f88fb14efb623b9047e89a628eb9c881c67b4d035995d9859918bb9', 'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:661211433270:stack/oracle/24520dd0-95e8-11ea-b1d1-0609694b6370', 'RequestId': 'ff43fa14-be13-4a66-95e5-ee0b82a44993', 'LogicalResourceId': 'RDSDBSetup', 'ResourceType': 'Custom::DBSetup', 'ResourceProperties': {'ServiceToken': 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:661211433270:function:oracle-rds-dbsetup-lambda', 'MasterSecretArn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:661211433270:secret:rds/app/master4-h4UyCN', 'AppUserGrants': ['CREATE SESSION', 'CONNECT', 'RESOURCE', 'DBA'], 'AppSecretArn': 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:661211433270:secret:rds/app/application4-3XnzKs'}}
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:14.50Z f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Found credentials in environment variables.
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.455Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    User created: testappdbuser
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.459Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Granted: CREATE SESSION
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.470Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Granted: CONNECT
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.475Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Granted: RESOURCE
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.479Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Granted: DBA
[INFO]  2020-05-14T13:54:15.480Z    f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2    Successfully created user testappdbuser in Oracle Server DB for secret arn arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-west-1:661211433270:secret:rds/app/application4-3XnzKs.
https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-euwest1.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-west-1%3A661211433270%3Astack/oracle/24520dd0-95e8-11ea-b1d1-0609694b6370%7CRDSDBSetup%7Cff43fa14-be13-4a66-95e5-ee0b82a44993?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200514T135412Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7MCS7PVEUOADEEA%2F20200514%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=20bb8ba39f88fb14efb623b9047e89a628eb9c881c67b4d035995d9859918bb9
Response body:
{
    "Status": "SUCCESS",
    "Reason": "See the details in CloudWatch Log Stream: 2020/05/14/[$LATEST]c85275eb57604aebb929853d877306c7",
    "PhysicalResourceId": "2020/05/14/[$LATEST]c85275eb57604aebb929853d877306c7",
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:661211433270:stack/oracle/24520dd0-95e8-11ea-b1d1-0609694b6370",
    "RequestId": "ff43fa14-be13-4a66-95e5-ee0b82a44993",
    "LogicalResourceId": "RDSDBSetup",
    "NoEcho": false,
    "Data": {}
}
send(..) failed executing requests.put(..): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='cloudformation-custom-resource-response-euwest1.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aeu-west-1%3A661211433270%3Astack/oracle/24520dd0-95e8-11ea-b1d1-0609694b6370%7CRDSDBSetup%7Cff43fa14-be13-4a66-95e5-ee0b82a44993?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200514T135412Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJ7MCS7PVEUOADEEA%2F20200514%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-**Signature=20bb8ba39f88fb14efb623b9047e89a628eb9c881c67b4d035995d9859918bb9 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fec35bc8610>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))**
END RequestId: f515ffc3-56d4-4301-96a5-426ab14c68a2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your Lambda function in a VPC without a NAT gateway? Looks like it doesn't have an outbound internet connection since it doesn't have an IP address.

Try removing the Lambda from the VPC if you don't need to access VPC private resources.

Otherwise, it also looks like you need to access RDS from within the Lambda, so in that case, you should add a NAT gateway to your VPC.

Some useful resources:

AWS Lambda: How to setup a NAT gateway for a lambda function with VPC access
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: I have created interface VPC endpoints for interaction between VPC resources and lambda function.

Comment: Seems like should be having an s3 gatway endpoint attached to  your VPC.  Please check the below link for more information https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cloudformation-templates/issues/100